# How do I only plot values over a certain number in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

my dataframe currently looks like this

```
N = 61
MChange <- rnorm(N)
FChange <- rnorm(N) 
Industry <- sample(N)
industry020406 <- data.frame(Industry, MChange, FChange)
```

Using the following code:

```
ggplot(industry020406, aes(reorder(Industry, MChange), MChange)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Industry",
       y = "Tariff Cut (Percentage Points)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  coord_flip()
```

my barchart looks like this:

[image]

Since it is difficult to identify changes that are significant, is there a way I can filter out MChange that is between `-1` and `1` within the `ggplot` function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the filtering in `xlim()`:

```r
x.lab <- with(industry020406, reorder(Industry, MChange)[MChange >= -1 & MChange <= 1])

ggplot(industry020406, aes(reorder(Industry, MChange), MChange)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  xlim(sort(x.lab))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just filter it as normal, e.g. with `dplyr::filter`

```r
ggplot(dplyr::filter(industry020406, MChange < 1 & MChange > - 1),
       aes(reorder(Industry, MChange), MChange)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Industry",
       y= "Tariff Cut (Percentage Points)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]